# Passing data to a BroadcastReceiver from a PendingIntent (AlarmManager)

Tags: android, kotlin

I’ve been playing around with local notifications.  I’m trying to pass data to the BroadcastReceiver; I’ve noticed that the below code works with lollipop however on my Nexus 6P with 7.1 doesn’t.

This is how i setup the intents and add the 'extra' data:

```
val am = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
val alarmIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
alarmIntent.putExtra("data", data)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), (1000 * 60).toLong(), pendingIntent) // Millisec * Second * Minute
```

In the BroadcastReceiver:

```
val pm = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "")
    wl.acquire()
    val data = intent.getParcelableExtra<MyData>("data")
```

Googling the issue doesn’t bring up much, what it does bring up is a SO post, and a comment mentioning this exact problem.  However i’ve not seen any solution and what i’ve tried isn’t working, so i was wondering if anyone has figured a way that it will work on 7.1?

Edit:

This is the data object:

```
data class MyData(val accountNumber: String, val date: Date, val key: Int) : Parcelable {
companion object {
    @JvmField val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator< MyData > = object : Parcelable.Creator< MyData > {
        override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): MyData = MyData(source)
        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array< MyData?> = arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}

constructor(source: Parcel) : this(
        source.readString(),
        source.readSerializable() as Date,
        source.readInt()
)

override fun describeContents() = 0

override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    dest.writeString(accountNumber)
    dest.writeSerializable(date)
    dest.writeSerializable(key)
}
```

}

Excerpt of the log when calling `val data = intent.getParcelableExtra<MyData>("data")`

05-19 21:06:37.076 8150-8220/com.wolfbane.example V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 864865
05-19 21:06:37.098 8150-8154/com.wolfbane.example I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=47KB, data=47KB
05-19 21:06:37.098 8150-8154/com.wolfbane.example I/art: After code cache collection, code=45KB, data=46KB
05-19 21:06:37.098 8150-8154/com.wolfbane.example I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
05-19 21:06:37.102 8150-8154/com.wolfbane.example I/art: JIT allocated 61KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
05-19 21:06:37.102 8150-8154/com.wolfbane.example I/art: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
05-19 21:06:37.151 8150-8154/com.wolfbane.example I/art: Do full code cache collection, code=111KB, data=79KB
05-19 21:06:37.151 8150-8154/com.wolfbane.example I/art: Starting a blocking GC JitCodeCache
05-19 21:06:37.151 8150-8154/com.wolfbane.example I/art: After code cache collection, code=71KB, data=40KB
05-19 21:06:42.079 8150-8220/com.wolfbane.example V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
05-19 21:06:42.829 8150-8157/com.wolfbane.example I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
05-19 21:07:04.396 8150-8157/com.wolfbane.example W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.531ms

Comment: Are you just receiving `null` back from the intent? Also, are you sure the data you passing is `Parcelable`?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it's always null.  Yes it's Parcelable.  Note that it works on Lollipop with no issues.

Comment: Is the data object `Parcelable`?

Comment: Ive updated the question with the Data class.

Comment: Either you have no extras in your intent (`intent.getExtras()` is `null`), or there is some sort of error being thrown with unparcelling your `MyData` object. Can show a LogCat when your app calls `val data = intent.getParcelableExtra<MyData>("data")`? There may be a warning from the OS.

Comment: Just update with an excerpt of the log.  Can't see any warnings or errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144692/discussion-between-pablo-baxter-and-wolfbane).

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution to this by [Isaac Jordan](https://isaacjordan.me/blog/2017/01/fix-android-parcelable-extras-being-null/)

The gist of it is to pass an array of bytes as the 'extra', rather than your Parcelable class i.e.

When adding your data to the intent:

```
val bytes = ParcelableUtil.marshall(data)
alarmIntent.putExtra("data", bytes)
```

Then on the receiving side you would read the data as follows:

```
val bytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("data")
val data = MyData(ParcelableUtil.unmarshal(bytes))
```

**ParcelableUtil in Kotlin**

```
class ParcelableUtil {
companion object {
    fun marshall(parcelable: Parcelable): ByteArray {
        val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
        parcelable.writeToParcel(parcel, 0)
        val bytes = parcel.marshall()
        parcel.recycle()
        return bytes
    }

    fun unmarshall(bytes: ByteArray): Parcel {
        val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
        parcel.unmarshall(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
        parcel.setDataPosition(0)
        return parcel
    }

    fun <T> unmarshall(bytes: ByteArray, creator: Parcelable.Creator<T>): T {
        val parcel = unmarshall(bytes)
        val result = creator.createFromParcel(parcel)
        parcel.recycle()
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use unmarshal on a class that has "Parcelize" annotation on it, though?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. The wrong, yet easy way: put the Parcelable object into a bundle, and the bundle as the one to insert into the Intent :

```
intent.putExtra("data", Bundle().also { it.putParcelable("realData", theParcelableObject) })
```

and query the bundle later:

```
val obj = intent.getBundleExtra("data")?.getParcelable<MyData>("realData")
```

Why this is wrong? Because the class might change on the next version of the app, and your PendingIntent might be caught then instead of the current version. This could result in you missing the data.

2. The correct way: save the data into DB, and put just the ID of the object into the Intent, and to get the data, perform the query with the DB. The disadvantage is that it's more work, and requires DB management. The advantage is that it's future proof, assuming you manage the DB well.